# Use Yast with a administrator account instead of the root account

Tags: suse, administration, yast

I am looking to disable my root account for security purposes only in witch I use sudo for anything I use on my system that I need the root account for. Witch works fine for if I need to do anything within the terminal. But when I open YaST2 it ask me for the root password and not mine.

And I am wondering if I can set YaST up to use my password sense the root password wont work scene it will be disabled.

**Update** I use opensuse tumbleweed along with MATE desktop environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: On KDE Plasma desktop it is possible to launch YaST and other tools which need root permission as non root user using the launcher.**

<s>**Disclaimer: This won't let you run YaST from the launcher as non root user! But you will be able to start a YaST GUI from the terminal with sudo.**</s>

To run the graphical user interface for YaST as a normal user with sudo permission, follow the steps below:

Configure **sudo** for your non root user.

1. Add your user to the wheel group by using the following commands:

   ```
   $ su
   ```

   and enter your root password.

   ```
   # usermod -aG wheel username
   ```
2. Change your **/etc/sudoers** file by using

   ```
   # visudo
   ```

   Now comment in the line with **%wheel** by removing the preceding **#**

   ```
   ## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
   %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       ALL
   ```

   and comment out the two following lines by adding a preceding **#**

   ```
   ## This allows use of an ordinary user account for administration of a freshly
   ## installed system. When configuring sudo, delete the two
   ## following lines:
   # Defaults targetpw   # ask for the password of the target user i.e. root
   # ALL   ALL=(ALL) ALL   # WARNING! Only use this together with 'Defaults targetpw'!
   ```

   now find the already commented in line beginning with **Defaults env_keep**

   ```
   Defaults        env_keep = "LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE ..."
   ```

   and add the words **DISPLAY** and **XAUTHORITY** to the end of the line but before the **"**. This will allow the normal user to start graphical user interfaces with root permission when using sudo.

   ```
   Defaults        env_keep = "... DISPLAY XAUTHORITY"
   ```

   you can now save and exit visudo.
3. Leave the root session and lock the root user account by typing

   ```
   # exit
   $ sudo passwd -l root
   ```

   - <s>and finally start a YaST Qt GUI from terminal by typing:</s>

     `sudo yast2 --qt`
   - <s>or if you prefer a GTK GUI</s>

     `sudo yast2 --gtk`
4. Now configure **kdesu** to use **sudo** instead of **su**

   - type this for configuring kdesu

     ```
     kwriteconfig5 --file kdesurc --group super-user-command --key super-user-command sudo
     ```
5. Logout and Login again

For more information about the sudo configuration visit:

- https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Administer_with_sudo
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#kdesu
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#gksu

Comment: I can use yast with sudo in terminal, but configuring gksu to use sudo fails and stills ask me for the root password.

Comment: The kdesu version works. Could you please update your question, by providing your openSUSE / SUSE version + used desktop environment? I will then look for a solution.